# DC Motor With PI 3 without l293d

Tags: pi-3, dc-motor

I have explored the web looking for controlling my 2 dc motors without l293d or something like that..

I couldn't understand why I need it and couln't find project without it or something familiar..

Therefore I have few questions:

1. What is it and what it does?
2. Can I run motor on PI 3 without it?
3. I have 1538HXL no idea what is it but can he replace l293d (cause it look the same as l293d) and if so someone have project for example?

Comment: L293D are called motor drivers, they drive the current to the Motor and RPi cannot provide current enough directly to drive the motors.

Comment: @MaNyYaCk This is why I use external power source

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the 1538HXL? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: How is your external power source connected if not through some sort of external chip?  You provided the external power but then also need to control the current flowing from that source into the motor with something external.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling a DC motor takes more power than the GPIO pins of a Raspberry Pi can directly source. In other words, if you try to connect a GPIO pin of a Raspberry Pi directly to a motor you will burn out the Pi.

You can control a DC motor in one direction with a transistor. [Here is an example.](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TransistorMotorControl) This example uses an Arduino rather than a Raspberry Pi, but the electronics are the same.

That is the easiest version of a motor controller. I tend to use prebuilt motor controller. Adafruit carries a couple Hats for the Pi. [This one controls up to 4 DC motors or 2 stepper motors.](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2348) [This one controls up to 2 DC motors.](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1940)

If you need to control a larger motor, there is an excellent group of motor controllers at [Servo City](https://www.servocity.com/electronics/motor-controllers). I use the RoboClaw series of controllers for my robots.

Comment: The Pi pins can probably source the power, the GPIO can not.

Comment: The power pins might be able to source the power for a small motor, but the controllable pins (the GPIO) cannot. Most of the Pi pins are GPIO, are they not? I will edit my answer to make that clear.